# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when moving APK to /system/priv-app/

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

After debugging my app successfully I want to move the app to the system apps so that I can make use of system permissions such as REBOOT and SET_TIME. However when moving my APK to /system/priv-app/ folder or adding the APK to a third party system app in the ROM compile I receive the following error when the APP is run:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load zbarjni from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/mcaster.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]:
```

I can debug and install and run the APK successfully via adb. 
I have tried most of the suggestions regarding UnsatisfiedLinkError such as the most common to add :

```
ndk { 
 abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"  
}
```

to gradle, however I still face the error.
(my CPU architecture is armeabi-v7a)

I would assume that since I can install the APK and run it successfully via ADB all the missing libraries are present in the APK, however there is obviously some different when working with the app as a system app.

Where else can I look to resolve this UnsatisfiedLinkError when moving my app to the system apps?

Answer (score 0):

I first succeeded to run the app after copying the APK to /system/priv-app/ by manually copying the .so files into /system/lib. This lead me to believe the problem lay in the compilation not doing the same.

Compiling the APK into the ROM as a system application, required Android.mk to include the following lines to copy the .so files from the project to the system/lib folder.
The ROM is specific to a certain device so the .so relevant to the architecture was included.

Android.mk

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += ${LOCAL_PATH}/lib/libiconv.so:system/lib/libiconv.so
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += ${LOCAL_PATH}/lib/libzbarjni.so:system/lib/libzbarjni.so
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += ${LOCAL_PATH}/lib/libopencv_java3.so:system/lib/libopencv_java3.so
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += ${LOCAL_PATH}/lib/libledcontrol_jni.so:system/lib/libledcontrol_jni.so
```

This resolved the UnsatisfiedLinkError as the files are now present in system/lib

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon XarionXRC's answer, here is a more generic way of using Android's build system to automatically extract and copy the libraries. You may need to replace `arm64-v8a` with the appropriate lib dir name, like `armeabi-v7a`.

In Android.mk

```
LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD = \
    rm -rf $(dir $(LOCAL_INSTALLED_MODULE))/lib; \
    unzip -qq -o -d $(dir $(LOCAL_INSTALLED_MODULE)) $(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE) 'lib/arm64-v8a/*.so'; \
    mv $(dir $(LOCAL_INSTALLED_MODULE))/lib/arm64-v8a $(dir $(LOCAL_INSTALLED_MODULE))/lib/arm64
```