# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when installing as system app

Tags: android

I build and installed this Traceroute [project](https://github.com/wangjing53406/traceroute-for-android) as a third party app and its working fine. But when I moved the APK to /system/priv-app/ folder to install it as a system app, getting an error like this when running traceroute -

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/TraceRoute/app-release.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/priv-app/TraceRoute/lib/arm, /system/priv-app/TraceRoute/app-release.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /product/lib, /system/lib, /product/lib]]] couldn't find "libtraceroute.so"
```

As per stack trace, the issue happens when the app tries to load the traceroute binary file by calling System.loadLibrary("traceroute")

Tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58792065/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-moving-apk-to-system-priv-app) but still facing the same issue. What can I do to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an APK is installed usually the .so files are extracted and saved so that they can be loaded by Linux/Android. When you just copy the APK as system app this does not work. Not sure where the .so files would have to be placed (the place may also change with the Android version). But you could try as workaround to make the .so files usable from within the APK file: Set [extractNativeLibs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#extractNativeLibs=false) in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<application android:extractNativeLibs="false" ...
```

This allows to directly load the .so files from the APK file without the need to extract them. Hopefully this also works for system apps and eliminates your problem.

Note that then your app needs to be zipaligned by 4096 and not by default 4:

```
zipalign 4096 infile.apk aligned_outfile.apk
```

Regular gradle build should already zipalign the APK correctly. This will also increase the APK file size a bit, as all .so files are saved without compression and every file entry in the APK/ZIP file is aligned to 4KB so if your APK contains a high number of files (e.g. resources like images) you may recognize a significant APK size increase.